# Change bean property/value during runtime in spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, multiple-databases

I am using spring mvc+hibernate+two databases

So for example:
I create 2 sessionFactories. `sessionFactory1` (using `datasource1`) and `sessionFactory2` (using `datasource2`).

Would it be possible to change `sessionFactory1` or `sessionFactory2` to sessionFactory at runtime so that the dao/s references them. sessionFactory is already autowired to all dao/s.

I am searching for it right now I think @Configuration can help me but I am not sure.

I am trying AbstractRoutingDataSource but don't think it helps.

Comment: not sure i get it, you could inject the right factory into each DAO?

Comment: Ok I am now able to change the database I use using AbstractDataSource with the help of
http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and then accept it for the benefit of users with the same issue.

Comment: Do you mean to say that two application contexts of spring should communicate with each other ? If so, look at http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractRoutingDataSource will work for you.

First you'll need to create a class that will store the current DB in use:

```
public class MyContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static void setDBContext(String dBContext) {
        contextHolder.set(dBContext);
    }

    public static String getDBContext() {
        return (String) contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDBContext() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }

}
```

You'll need to create a class that extends this one and implements determineCurrentLookupKey(), and return the current db you have in your context holder:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class MyRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return MyContextHolder.getDBContext();
    }
}
```

See the example in http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/.
It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Spring wires your beans on application startup, so "re-wiring" (replacing references to sessionFactory1 with references to sessionFactory2 on runtime) does not seem easy to implement.

Maybe you could implement a "proxy bean" that is wired to your DAO objects and change the "target SessionFactory" of your proxy bean.